# does Delayed_job daemon not run in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm using delayed_job and I am able to run jobs using rake jobs:work but using the daemonized version, it does nothing although I see it in the process list.

I'm using:

- rails (3.0.9)
- delayed_job (2.1.4)
- daemons (1.0.10)

I'm running delayed_job using:

```
unix>RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job start
```

Comment: What's the result of `RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job status` ?

Comment: Did you try to run it without daemons gem?

Comment: Gemfile.lock states daemons is a required dependency but I'll remove explicit use and try it. Reason I did that was try and force Daemonize to use a particular version (a lot of StackOverflow suggestions revolved around using 1.0.10 for daemons) since I had daemons 1.1.4 on the system.

Answer (score 4):

It could be a problem loading a custom job class file. To test that, try this:

- Enter the rails console `rails console --sandbox`.
- Make sure you have a job in the table `job = Delayed::Job.first`.
- Try `YAML.load(job.handler)`. If you get an error that looks like this: `ArgumentError: undefined class/module MyCustomClass`, it's probably a problem loading your custom job
- Still in the rails console, run `require 'My_Custom_Class`. Then run the `YAML.load(job.handler)` command again. If this returns the appropriate object it's definitely a class loading problem.

To fix the problem create the file `config/initializers/custom.rb` and in it put `require 'My_Custom_Class'`.

You should then be able to run `rake jobs::workoff` and get something that looks like this:

```
[Worker(host:my.host pid:5085)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:my.host pid:5085)] MyCustomJob completed after 0.0774
[Worker(host:my.host pid:5085)] 1 jobs processed at 9.1935 j/s, 0 failed ...
[Worker(host:my.host pid:5085)] No more jobs available. Exiting
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question we may need more information.

Are jobs added to database? Are there any errors in jobs?

What's the result of `RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job status` as I already mentioned?

Second, did you went through the most common problems Wiki page?

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems

Comment: jobs are added to the database. They are not processed by the daemon but are processed by rake jobs:work. I shall check on the delayed job status message but I see that it's running (when I do start twice, it says a process is already running) + the pid in the delayed_job.log matches the pid of the ruby delayed_job process.

Comment: Status returns `delayed_job: running [pid 1473]`